# Is there a standard mysql connection pooling library for C?

Tags: mysql, c, performance, connection-pooling

I have a C application using the [MySQL library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html) for database access.

Is there a standard way to implement database connection pooling for such an application?
The [C connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-c.html) doesn't appear to support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Zild Database Library](http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/), "a thread-safe high level multi-database connection pool library", looks very promising.

Previously I suggested that
[SQL Relay](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/) could be used to do this, amongst many other useful things, such as

- client-side caching
- load-balancing across database instances
- translating between different database access APIs

If the MySQL library is dynamically linked this can be done without recompiling the application.

When I last looked in 2009, the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum=sqlrelay-discussion) suggested SQL Relay might not be fully ready for production use, but that appears to have changed.

Comment: Comments on experience with SQL Relay, and other suggestions welcome!